# Selenium - getting text by XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath

Why this XPath couldn't find text? When I paste it in development tools XPath work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_experimental_option( "prefs",{'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript': 2})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.atptour.com/en/tournaments')
time.sleep(5)
name_of_surface = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentAccordionWrapper']/div[9]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/span")
print(f'Name of surface: {name_of_surface.get_attribute("text")}')
```

Comment: Did you try `name_of_surface.text` or `name_of_surface.get_attribute("innerText")`?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to locate? And i am not sure how you are saying **When I paste it in development tools XPath work** because i tried and it not matching even in element in there as well.

Comment: I tried to find "Hard", you can't find element because he is hide. You should click on august month or disable javascript on website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your xPath there is one mistake at`//[@id='contentAccordionWrapper']/div[9]/div[2]/table` as after div[2] there is one more div between table and this div. Better way is to ise double slash `//`. It will insure to find any child table.

```
//[@id='contentAccordionWrapper']/div[9]/div[2]//table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/span'
```

**Note:** Above will give you text

> Hard

Let us know what exactly you are trying to locate so that can provide a more efficient xpath , rather than long ine you have used.